# Ansible - Write multiple line output to file

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to gather information from remote nodes and will then use this information to update relevant RPMs.

The issue I am having is collection version number of various applications and writing them to a file.

Playbook:

```
---
  - name: Check Application Versions
    hosts: kubernetes
    tasks:
       - name: Check K8S version.
         shell: kubectl --version
         register: k8s_version

       - debug: msg="{{ k8s_version.stdout }}"
```

Inventory file:

```
[kubernetes]
172.29.219.102 
172.29.219.105 
172.29.219.104 
172.29.219.103
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [172.29.219.102] => {
    "msg": "Kubernetes v1.4.0"
}
ok: [172.29.219.103] => {
    "msg": "Kubernetes v1.4.0"
}
ok: [172.29.219.105] => {
    "msg": "Kubernetes v1.4.0"
}
ok: [172.29.219.104] => {
    "msg": "Kubernetes v1.4.0"
}
```

The above portion is simple and works. Now I want to write the output to file.

Now im trying to write this information to a file.I want something like:

Kubernetes v1.4.0
Kubernetes v1.4.0
Kubernetes v1.4.0
Kubernetes v1.4.0

So I added the below line:

```
- local_action: copy content={{ k8s_version.stdout_lines }} dest=/tmp/test
```

My `/tmp/test` looks like :

```
# cat /tmp/test 
["Kubernetes v1.4.0"]
```

There is only one value here.

I tried to do something different then.

```
- local_action: lineinfile dest=/tmp/foo line="{{ k8s_version.stdout }}" insertafter=EOF
```

This resulted in:

```
# cat  /tmp/foo 
Kubernetes v1.4.0
```

Im trying to figure out why I only see one value whereas I should see the versions of every node in my inventory file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the copy module overwrites the file content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong ?

`lineinfile` module does not perform the action "add a line to a file", instead it ensures a given line is present in the file. If all your target nodes have the same version, it won't add the same line multiple times.

On the other hand, `copy` module was overwriting the file.

---

If you need to register values for all hosts, you can for example create a template which will loop over hosts in the `kubernetes` group:

```
- copy:
    content: "{% for host in groups.kubernetes %}{{ hostvars[host].k8s_version }}\n{% endfor %}"
    dest: /tmp/test
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

Another way would be to extract the values with `map` from `hostvars`, but given you want the values from `kubernetes` host group only, I'm not sure it would be prettier. And having a `for` in the template allows you to easily add host names.

Answer (score 3):

According to this post

[Ansible register result of multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881762/ansible-register-result-of-multiple-commands)

your desired variable is in `k8s_version.results` To access it you need to work with a template where you just iterate over it:

```
- local_action: template src=my_nodes.j2 dest=/tmp/test
```

And the template `templates/my_nodes.j2` :

```
 {% for res in k8s_version.results %}
     {{ res.stdout }}
 {% endfor %}
```

The complete playbook would then be:

```
---
  - name: Check Application Versions
    hosts: kubernetes
    tasks:
       - name: Check K8S version.
         shell: kubectl --version
         register: k8s_version

       - local_action: template src=my_nodes.j2 dest=/tmp/test
```

Comment: It will overwrite the file in the same way `copy` module does. The example in the other answer registers the value in a `with_`-loop. The example in this question does not.

Comment: That is: it would overwrite, but in reality won't have a chance to. It will fail first for the reason of the key being undefined.

Comment: {% for res in logshellexec.results %}{{ res.stdout }}\n{% endfor %}