# Ansible, error in getting results for multiple register command

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I tried to get results as follow:

```
- name: Populate known_hosts
  hosts: spectrum_scale
  gather_facts: no
  tags: set_known_hosts
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Get hosts list from known_host
    ansible.builtin.shell:
      cmd: "cat /root/.ssh/known_hosts |
              grep {{ hostvars[item].ansible_fqdn }}"
    with_items: "{{groups['spectrum_scale']}}"
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: hosts2add

  - name: Scan for SSH client keys
    ansible.builtin.shell:
      cmd: "ssh-keyscan {{ hostvars[h2a_r.item].ansible_fqdn }},
                        {{ hostvars[h2a_r.item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
                        2>/dev/null"
    loop: "{{ hosts2add.results }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: h2a_r
    when: h2a_r.rc
    register: ssh_scan


  - name: Display debug
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "FINGERPRINT TO ADD {{ ss_r.stdout_lines }}"
      # var: ss_r.stdout_lines   
    loop: "{{ ssh_scan.results }}"
    loop_control:
       loop_var: ss_r
```

I got the error:

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'
```

What's really weird is that if use the var instead of msg I got the value I need

```
var: ss_r.stdout_lines
```

I found an old post ([Ansible register result of multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881762/ansible-register-result-of-multiple-commands)) but that solutions suggested seem not work for me

Thank you for helping

Comment: The propertiy is actually stdout_line**s** (mind the S). https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout-lines

Comment: You're right, there was a typo. The original code was correct and the error is still the same. 
With var this is the output 
`"ss_r.stdout_lines": [
        "n02....., ssh-rsa ...."]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works if you already have all the hosts in the `known_hosts` file. In this case commands are always executed and variables are defined.
In case your `known_hosts` is empty, and you run "Display debug" printing var there will be an output as follow:

```
"ss_r.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

So in order to have the task failing you need to specify:

```
when: ss_r.stdout_lines is defined
```

For the sake of completeness here there is the complete task working:

```
 - name: Display debug
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "FINGERPRINT TO ADD {{ ss_r.stdout_lines }}"
    loop: "{{ ssh_scan.results }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: ss_r
    when: ss_r.stdout_lines is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but `result` is a dictionary who contains all the values you stored.

if you're going to use `loop` for loops you need to pass `dict2items`

E.G.:

```yaml
  - name: Display debug
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "FINGERPRINT TO ADD {{ ss_r.stdout_lines }}"
      # var: ss_r.stdout_lines   
    loop: "{{ ssh_scan.results | dict2items }}"
    loop_control:
       loop_var: ss_r
```

Probably that resolve the error message you stated before.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I've already tried to deal with it as dict, but with no success. 
`FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ ssh_scan.results | dict2items }}): dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'list'> instead."}`